# Why didn't I get tan(PI /2) = infinty in C

Tags: c

When I calculate tan(PI/2) I get -22877332 in c, but tan(Pi/2) is infinity.
and google giving it as 3060023.30695 Why i am getting different answer

I tried on mingw compiler and in google both are giving different answer

```
float32 Tan_f32 (float32 ValValue )
{
float32 Result_Val;

 Result_Val= (tanf(ValValue));
 return Result_Val;
 }
```

in  mingw compiler it gives -22877332
and in google 3060023.30695

Comment: Please make a [mcve] and give more details about your environment.

Comment: Floating point number are not precise. You are calculating (an approximation) of tan of a number near PI/2

Comment: How did you try this on Google? Did you type some expression into the Google search engine? What expression?

Comment: The [Google Calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=tan(pi%2F2)&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB826GB826&oq=tan(pi%2F2)&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j6j0l3.3398j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) returns 1.6331239e+16 for me; how are you getting 3060023.30695?

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible to pass π/2 to `tan` or `tanf` because π is irrational, so any floating-point number, no matter how precise, will be at least slightly different from π/2. Therefore, `tanf(ValValue)` returns the tangent of some value close to π/2, and that tangent is large but not infinite.

In the common format used for `float`, IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point, the closest representable number to π/2 is 1.57079637050628662109375. The tangent of that number is approximately −22877332.4289, and the closest value representable in `float` is −22877332, which is the result you got. So your `tanf` is giving you the best possible result for the input number you gave it.

Comment: I agree @ Eric Postpischil but then how I get exact answer in calculator .. also why I didnt get same answer from google and code??

Comment: @VikrantDaharwal: Your code gives you the best possible answer for the input value you used. I edited my answer to show this. Your calculator likely uses some symbolic math, not floating point. That is, it manipulates some things as mathematical expressions, like “π+sqrt(2)”, rather than as numbers. In that case, it is possible to pass exactly π/2 to a tangent routine, because π/2 is representable in a system of symbolic mathematical expressions. We cannot say why Google gave you a different answer because you have not shown us what you typed into Google.

Comment: You maybe could also get infinity numerically when the result is too big to be represented by the type even if the operand is slightly different form `pi/2`. EDIT: (I think that does not apply to `float` or `double` but maybe to the type the calculator is using)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes I already edited my comment that this maybe applies to the calculator, but not for `float` or `double`.

Comment: @Osiris: Ah, possible. It is a bit unlikely, though. Modeled probabilistically, the deviation between a representable number and some multiple of π/2 tends to be not much less than an ULP. (It could be much less than an ULP only if π/2, written in the base used for floating-point, had a bunch of zeros or “nines”, at a particular spot. So the tangents of representable values tend to be not much more than 1/ULP. E.g., around π/2, the ULP of 32-bit is 2^−23, and note OP’s result is between 2^23 and 2^24. But the exponent lets us range up to 2^128.…

Comment: … so it would take around a hundred bits of zeros or “nines” (ones in binary) to cause `tanf(x)` to overflow to ∞. And the number of shots we have at getting this close is less than the number of representable numbers (less than 2^32 for 32-bit). Pretty “unlikely” if chance were involved.

Comment: Hm, yes for this exponent and mantissa it is probably impossible. This works only if we take some non standard types in account where you can choose an arbitrary combination of exponent and mantissa width (As you said 8bit exponent and 128bit mantissa for example).

Answer (score 3):

The C standard, or indeed the common but by no means ubiquitous IEEE754 floating point standard, give no guarantee of the accuracy of `tan` (*Cf* `sqrt`). An implementation will make a compromise in getting a good result out in a reasonable number of clock cycles.

In particular, the behaviour of the trigonometric function near an asymptote is particularly unpredictable; and that's the case here.

Accepting that the fault is not due to your value of *pi* (worth a check although note that because *pi* is transcendental it can't be represented exactly in any floating point system), if you want a well-behaved `tan` function across the whole domain, you'll be better off using a third party mathematics library.

Finally, note that under IEEE754, you *might* get more consistent behaviour around an asyptote if you let floating point division deal with the pole, and use

```
double c = cos(x); tan(x) = sqrt(1 / c / c  - 1);
```

This might be more numerically stable, as IEEE754 *defines* a division by zero.

Comment: Thanks @ Bathsheba , can you tell me which third  party math library we can use.? or can I change the code to get accurate result

Comment: @VikrantDaharwal: Ha. That's the million dollar question! Luckily I can hide behind the Stack Overflow policy of not recommending tools, but your decision is a function of accuracy vv. compute time.

Comment: @VikrantDaharwal: I've put up an idea which might be better for you numerically.

Comment: As you know, “Accepting that the fault is not due to your value of pi” is not the case. The value OP is using for π is not π, and the value they are getting for `tanf(ValValue)` is the best result possible in the format for the input closest to π/2. So the `tanf` function is not at fault here; it gave the most accurate result possible for the input it was given. Using `cos` cannot improve the result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Indeed not the result but perhaps the consistency. My asking the OP to check *pi* is more to guard against code like `double pi = 3.14;`.